# .parent() inside multiple selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, multiple-select-query

I want to select a couple of targets:

1. Every direct `li` descendant whose parent is **not** `.sub-menu` (unless it's the last, cf. 2.)
2. Every last li element of an `ul.sub-menu`
3. **Exclude** all `li`'s that are parent to a `ul.sub-menu`

I was thinking something like this, but that doesn't seem to work: `$("ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last, ('ul.sub-menu').parent()")`

How would one go about when trying to select an element with non-css selectors inside multiple selectors?

Comment: I would split it into three different selectors, then combine the collections with .add after.

Comment: `('ul.sub-menu').parent()"` What is this doing inside your selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child').not(':has(ul.sub-menu)');
```

Comment: Maybe, if you had some time, you could help out with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293673/or-and-and-combinations-inside-if-statement Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`$('ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child, li:not(:has(ul.sub-menu))')`