# OR and AND combinations inside if-statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors

I have this selector:

`$('ul:not(.sub-menu) > li, ul.sub-menu > li:last-child').not(':has(ul.sub-menu)');`

which gets these elements:

1. Every direct `li` descendant whose parent is **not** `.sub-menu` (unless it's the last, cf. 2.)
2. Every last li element of an `ul.sub-menu`
3. **Exclude** all `li`'s that are parent to a `ul.sub-menu`

Now, I want to use this in an if-statement, which is inside a hover-function. In other words, it's got to be relative to that list item instead of *being* the list item.

Something like this:

```
$("nav li").hover(function () {
  var $this = $(this); 
  if (($this.parent("ul:not(.sub-menu)") || ($this.parent("ul.sub-menu") && $this.is(":last-child"))) && $this.not(":has(ul.sub-menu)")) {
     // do something
  }
});
```

But this does not work. I think it has something to do with combining the OR and AND selectors inside an if-statement, but I can't seem to debug it: the code above selects all list items without a distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this.parent("ul:not(.sub-menu)")` is never falsy, even if the set is empty.

Use `$this.parent("ul:not(.sub-menu)").length` instead in your condition.

The whole if statement would thus look like this :

```
if (
    (
        $this.parent("ul:not(.sub-menu)").length
        || ( $this.parent("ul.sub-menu").length && $this.is(":last-child") )
    ) && !$this.hasClass("sub-menu")
) {
     // do something
}
```

---

Details :

```
if ($('#a')) { // always verified

if ($('#a').length>0) { // verified if there is an element with id a

if ($('#a').length) { // identical to last one
```

As written by [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) :

> Examples of expressions that can be converted to false are those that
>   evaluate to null, 0, the empty string (""), or undefined

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? What would the if-statement look like then? And what should `length` be compared with? `=== 0`?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works indeed (but I changed the last line to: `!$this.hasClass("has-sub-menu")`. But, as you can see in my first post, I have a similar problem (didn't think it was worthy another topic) that I can't seem to solve.

Already +1 for your effort though!